# how to update table using temporary table in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ES3( 
    Select T148001,T148002,T148003,T148006  
    From T148 where T148008 = Monthy and T148009 = Yeary and T148007 = ID 
); 

update SalaryTable , ES3 src 
Set  Present = T148003, WorkingDay = T148002,  Overtime = T148006    
Where Empid = T148001 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

***As the sample code is following as:***

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Groups (Id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR(31), GroupId VARCHAR(31), ValWithinGroup INTEGER);
```

---

```
INSERT INTO Groups VALUES (NULL, "Davy", "Boy", 2);
INSERT INTO Groups VALUES (NULL, "Mary", "Girl", 2);
INSERT INTO Groups VALUES (NULL, "Bill", "Boy", 5);
INSERT INTO Groups VALUES (NULL, "Jill", "Girl", -3);
INSERT INTO Groups VALUES (NULL, "Fred", "Boy", 3);
```

---

***# Find the lowest value for each group***

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE GroupSum AS SELECT GroupId, MIN(ValWithinGroup)
AS baseVal FROM Groups GROUP BY GroupId;
```

***# create an index so mySQL can efficiently match***

ALTER TABLE GroupSum ADD UNIQUE (GroupId);

***# finally, make the baseline adjustment***

```
UPDATE Groups LEFT JOIN GroupSum USING (GroupId)
SET ValWithinGroup=ValWithinGroup-baseVal;
SELECT * FROM Groups;
```